What term do you use to describe to the rate of change of higher order tensor functions with respect to their inputs?
If the rate of change of a scalar valued function is the gradient, and the rate of change of a vector valued function is the Jacobian, what is the rate of a change of a matrix valued function?
To add some additional detail to this:
The rate of change of a function with vector input (1-order tensor) and scalar output (0-order tensor) can be described by the gradient vector (1-order tensor).
The rate of change of a function with vector input (1-order tensor) and vector output (1-order tensor) can be described by the Jacobian matrix (2-order tensor).
So the rate of change of a function with vector input (1-order tensor) and matrix output (2-order tensor) can be describe by the _____________ (3-order tensor)?
Jacobian tensor would make sense to me, but I am not finding any sources describing it as such. What would be the common term for this type of tensor to describe the rate of change of a function's output with respect to its input?

Yes, it's a third-order tensor. To my mind the cleanest way to talk about this is just to say that the derivative of a map $F : V \to W$ between two vector spaces is (at a given point) a linear map $V \to W$; many people seem to tremendously overcomplicate this issue for some reason. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative.
